# Smooth-out midi controller input in MainStage

Tags: logic-pro, midi-controller-keyboard, live

I often use midi controllers (such as expression pedals) to control synth parameters (cutoff & LFOs mostly) in a live environment. The only thing is, I often press my pedal too quickly and the transition isn't smooth.

Is there a way (plugin or built-in to mainstage) to smooth the input I give to my controller?

For example:
if I press on my pedal and move it from 0 to 127 in 0.3 seconds,
is there a way to tell mainstage to smoothly make the transition to 127 in 2.5 seconds instead?

It really would make sound transitions less jaring during a live performance.

P.S.

I did not add the MainStage tag as I currently am missing 50 reps to do so.

Comment: Nice idea, but that really is quite a complex instruction set. Not that it *couldn't* be done, but whether it's ever been implemented in any DAW...

Comment: Are you using USB midi or plain din to get the MIDI from the controllers? Would you be ready for an "home made solution"? Idk Mainstage but basically what you want it's to apply a very low pass filter on the data given by the controller.

Comment: You could quickly create a simple solution for this. For example create a program that filters certain midi events, remembers the velocity as some sort of target velocity and then periodically sends midi events with the velocity going towards the target with some speed restraints (for example constant rate or a rate proportional to the difference to the target velocity, but at least 1).

Comment: @Lazy - 'create a program'… that's a bit like saying, "To get to the moon, just make a rocket"

Comment: @Tetsujin It is not really that difficult. If you can get this Mainstage thing to work with JACK you can for example simply use the python jack module for this.

Comment: You could try to round that up into a proper answer. Right now, we've got so far as "To get to the moon, make a rocket… using metal, if you can find the right metal"

Comment: @Tetsujin I could try, but as I do not use MacOS and Mainstage I cannot test everything.